# Crystal: abstract static method

Tags: crystal-lang

Is it possible to define abstract static methods?

I'm trying:

```
abstract struct MyStruct
  abstract def self.myfun  # ERR
  abstract def MyStruct::myfun  # ERR
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abstract class methods don't appear to be a language feature:

```
abstract class Abstract
  abstract self.doit
end
# => Syntax error in /home/bmiller/test.cr:23: unexpected token: self
```

However you could always delegate to an instance:

```
abstract class Parent
  def self.instance
    @@instance ||= new
  end

  def self.doit
    instance.doit
  end

  abstract def doit
end

class Child < Parent
  def doit
    "ok"
  end
end

p Parent.doit # => can't instantiate abstract class Parent
p Child.doit # => "ok"
```

Comment: An instance method plus a singleton is a workaround, but it could be a solution

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem and figured out a (in my opinion) nicer solution:

```
abstract class Something
  module ClassMethods
    abstract def some_abstract_class_method
  end

  extend ClassMethods

  abstract def some_abstract_instance_method
end
```

The documentation mentions that *module methods* can be made *abstract* as well, so this builds on top of that.

Implementing this class without implementing the class method `some_abstract_class_method` will raise an error, as expected.